# Режим работы php как модуль apache. Как обновить версию php?

Tags: php, apache, администрирование, isp

Есть vps, стоит панель ispmanager. Оптимизирую сайт сделанный на битриксе.

Захотел сменить режим работы php с FastCGI на "как модуль Apache" и (см скрин) нет выбора php только 5.3 и точно так же если хочу выбрать Nginx + php-fpm как обновить версию php ?

Подскажите как можно это исправить и обновиться до php 5.6, в администрирование чуть больше нуба.
**стоит centos 6.8 и isp 5.78**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вы не указали какая у Вас **OS** и версия **ispmanager**.
Как пишут в мануалах :

*Внимание! Если на сервере установлена панель ISPmanager 5, то меняйте версию PHP только с помощью модуля панели "Возможности" - "Альтернативные версии PHP".*

Но по моему скромному опыту юзая только возможности панели связываете себя по рукам и ногам , зачастую гораздо проще сделать вручную. Обычно обновление php выглядит так :

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install php5
```

Comment: стоит centos 6.8 и isp 5.78, выбор версий php в режиме fast CGI есть вплоть до 7 версии,  я не могу понять почему такого выбора нет в других вариантах php?

Answer (score 1):

Обновление версии PHP в Centos.

Обновление PHP или установка будут производиться из репозитория Remi, поэтому произведем его подключение.

**Centos 5**
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-5.rpm

**Centos 6**
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm

**Centos 7**
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm

После установки пакета нужной версии репозитория, у Вас появится соответствующий файл: /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo

Теперь необходимо включить нужную версию PHP. Для этого редактируем /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo. Сейчас он содержит:

```
[remi]
name=Les RPM de remi pour Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/remi/$basearch/
mirrorlist=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/remi/mirror
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi

[remi-php55]
name=Les RPM de remi de PHP 5.5 pour Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/php55/$basearch/
mirrorlist=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/php55/mirror
# WARNING: If you enable this repository, you must also enable "remi"
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi

[remi-php56]
name=Les RPM de remi de PHP 5.6 pour Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/php56/$basearch/
mirrorlist=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/php56/mirror
# WARNING: If you enable this repository, you must also enable "remi"
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
```

На примере Centos 6, где по умолчанию предоставляется версия PHP 5.3, для обновления до 5.4 достаточно установить enabled=1 в главной секции [remi].

```
[remi]
name=Les RPM de remi pour Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/remi/$basearch/
mirrorlist=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/remi/mirror
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
```

После чего выполняем команду:

**yum install php -y** и наслаждаемся новой версией PHP. Для работы с apache mod_php этот способ так же работает.

Если нужно обновить версиюю до 5.5, то включаем ветку remi-php55 и снова одновляем php. Для версии 5.6 аналогично.

Решил вопрос с помощью [этого поста](https://proadminz.ru/neskolko-versiy-php-i-obnovlenie-php-v-isp-manager/comment-page-1/)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/119183)

Comment: сейчас поправлю .